# How can I draw a nested constellation diagram using smart diagrams?

Tags: smartdiagram

I am trying to draw a nested constellation diagram to show the classification. An example is given at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/smart-constellation/. I want to show further classification. For instance, *converter* is categorized into say *online* and *offline*. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a tikz mindmap, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78846/creating-thicker-tikz-mindmap-connectors for an example

Comment: Yes, I am using the same.